# Fluent Nhibernate : One-To-Many trouble

Tags: database, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a "Activity" entity, this entity can have several "Task".

**Here the code for the entities :**

```
public class Activity : Entity<int>
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public Activity()
    {
        Tasks = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Task>(); 
    }
}

public class Task
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; } 
}
```

**The mapping :**

```
public ActivityMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
    Map(x => x.Code);
    Map(x => x.Name);

    HasMany(x => x.Tasks)
        .KeyColumns.Add("Activity")
        .AsSet()
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}

public TaskMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
    Map(x => x.Code);
    Map(x => x.Name);
}
```

**The test :**

```
activity = new Activity
{
    Code = "...",
    Name = "..."
};

Task task = new Task
{
    Code = "...",
    Name ="...",
    Activity = activity
};
session.Save(activity);
```

I see whit NHProf 2 insert.
After the commit, I do a GetById of the entity "Activity" but the "Tasks" property is empty. In the database, the field "Activity" (entity "Task") is null.

Comment: Hey kris, was the problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
activity = new Activity
{
    Code = "...",
    Name = "..."
};

Task task = new Task
{
    Code = "...",
    Name ="...",
    Activity = activity
};
activity.Tasks.Add(task);
session.Save(activity);
```

You have to keep the relation between two objects in both sides.

P.S. maybe you should change the cascade to be `.Cascade.All();` because when I tryed Delete orphan it just didn't seem to work right.

**Update:** as @Stefan Steinegger mentioned you didn't Map the activity.

```
public TaskMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
    Map(x => x.Code);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    References( x => x.Activity); //Missing mapping 
}
```

But you still need to update the relation in both sides.

Comment: It's strange because with NHProg I see an Insert for Task and another for Ativity. The solution 2 should work, I tried with your code, same, I see 2 insert but "Activity" field is still null. Let's me try the first.

Comment: Strange when I generate de database there is no "Activity" field in table "Task" and the value is null. But there is a field "Activity_id" not null. I tried to set ".KeyColumns.Add("Activity")".

Comment: @Kris-I, Did you add this line `References( x => x.Activity);` in the mapping?

Comment: yesu of course. I see the 2 insert (one in activity and the other in task)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't map the Activity property of the task.